# Excel 'conditional formatting' formula issue with multiple condition ranges

Tags: formatting, conditional-statements, formula

Original formula works perfectly, using COUNTIFS, when the two ranges I'm comparing are the same exact shape. (#rows & #columns)

```
=COUNTIFS('G2-2'!$BB$1:$BB$15,$H101, 'G2-2'!$BC$1:$BC$15,-1)
```

But the moment I try this where one range is larger, $BE$1:$BO$15, it doesn't work!

```
=COUNTIFS('G2-2'!$BE$1:$BO$15,$S101, 'G2-2'!$BC$1:$BC$15,-1)
```

The idea is that on any particular row (i.e. Column Z in the example) where the formula resides on the 'Data' sheet; IF Col BC=-1 from sheet 'G2-2' and Col S from sheet 'Data' (=$S101) contains a value (an Area Code) within this range ('G2-2'!$BE$1:$BO$15) on sheet 'G2-2', as seen below, THEN the statement is TRUE and the formatting is applied.

As an example: 
Say the formula was in Col Z on 'Data' sheet and in a row with **TX as State and 214 as Area Code** in Col S as seen below. And since the corresponding row on sheet **'G2-2' Col BC=-1** from sheet 'G2-2' and the **value '214' is also contained in sheet 'G2-2' within the range ('G2-2'!$BE$1:$BO$15)** as seen below, SO the statement is TRUE and the formatting is applied.

**sheet: 'Data'**

**Col H        Col S        Col T          Col Z**

State  Area Code  State Group   Sheet G2-2

TX           214        Group A        (-1)Blacked Out

TX           214        Group A        (-1)Blacked Out

**sheet: 'G2-2'**

**Col BB  Col BC  Col BE  Col BF**

**Row 7**    TX      -1         214       469

Comment: Here's a sample Workbook.xlsm with a slightly larger table sample: www.onlineautomation.com/download/Workbook2.xlsm

Answer (score 0):

The [official documentation](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) is specific:

[image: Warning]